# How to use Facebook PHP API to upload a photo to wall without file POST? (Using a URL maybe?)

Tags: php, facebook, ipad, upload, photo

I'm doing preliminary research for an upcoming project. Basically here is the user/data flow:

- A webcam at an event takes pictures and sends the photos to a local server
- A brand rep has an iPad with an app (developed as an HTML app saved to iPad home screen as an app). The app displays all photos from the local server as thumbnails via simple AJAX calls to load them into the view.
- A user selects a photo. That photo will be sent from our local server to our remote server. The remote server will host a Facebook iFrame tab with the user selected photos.
- At the same time, a link to the iFrame tab with a query string will be posted on the user's Facebook wall and Twitter (if they choose to authenticate of course).

Now the tricky part, we are 99% sure that the client is going to want to also upload the photo directly to the Facebook user's album. Possibly to TwitPic as well but that is a secondary concern. So my question is, is there a way to use PHP to upload a photo to a Facebook wall without using a typical html file input field and POST? Ideally, if we can do some kind of a file_get_contents on the photo URL from the local server and use PHP/FB API to upload the contents of the photo URL, we'd be in great shape.

The goal is to have the photo uploaded to the user wall with a caption like:

> Check out my photo taken at **_** event! ***[URL to client facebook tab with photo id]***.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for cURL? http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: Perhaps... but I don't know much about cURL at all. I've only copied and pasted other peoples code to do specific things. Can you point me in the direction I am looking for? How does cURL play into the typical upload process specifically in FB? According to this link: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/ to upload, you simply do a POST with a file to a URL generated by the API for uploading.

Comment: Yeah I don't know much about facebook necessarily, but cURL allows you to POST from within a PHP script instead of submitting a form. Here's an example (googled: curl post example) http://davidwalsh.name/execute-http-post-php-curl

Comment: Take a look at the second example on the blog post you just referenced. The code beginning at '//Create a New Album' shows one way to POST information to a URL without using a form. cURL is another.

Comment: You do not need to have a form to POST something.

Comment: @cpilko nice. I'm guessing their SDK uses cURL, but a wrapper is very convenient.

Answer (score 0):

@jeremyharris is right to say that Facebook's PHP SDK wraps cURL. You indeed need to use cURL to post a request to Facebook's API endpoint. Though, start by reading http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ *Publishing* section to understand the mechanics before you jump onto their [SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdks/).

Then familiarise with the [feed object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/). You can use either it or the [photo](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/) object to upload the photo.