# Facebook App image post externally

Tags: facebook, image

is there a code or what is the code used on this app to be posted on a Facebook account once log in?

once you finish the steps you can post the created app post the image on your Facebook page

sample site:  http://www.dragulator.com/

does it has to do with the API key from the Facebook account?
I hope i am clear about what i want to achieve

Sincerely,

Jim

Answer (score 0):

To upload a photo on user's Facebook wall you need to use their API, called Graph. There are quiet a [few examples online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040848/how-to-use-facebook-php-api-to-upload-a-photo-to-wall-without-file-post-using), so I won't go into details, but the flow is:

1. Authenticate user to the app (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) and get the `access token`.
2. Initiate a post request with to create a post (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/).